# What matrix properties related with this matrix formula?

Tags: linear-algebra

vector $w, w^*, x_k$ and scalar $\rho_k$

$$w_{k+1}-w^*=w_k-w^*+\rho_kx_k$$

squaring both sides then

$$\lVert w_{k+1}-w^*\rVert^2=\lVert w_k-w^* \rVert^2+2\rho_k(w_k-w^*)^Tx_k+\rho^2_k\lVert x_k\rVert^2$$

in this formula, why that transpose of the vector $w_k-w^*$ appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two vectors $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$, then

\begin{align*}
\lVert \mathbf x + \mathbf y\rVert^2&=(\mathbf x + \mathbf y)^T (\mathbf x + \mathbf y)\\
&=\mathbf x^T \mathbf x + \mathbf x^T \mathbf y + \mathbf y^T \mathbf x + \mathbf y^T \mathbf y\\
&= \lVert \mathbf x\rVert^2 + 2\mathbf x^T \mathbf y + \lVert \mathbf y\rVert^2
\end{align*}

You are just applying this to $\mathbf x = w_k-w^\ast$ and $\mathbf y = \rho_k x_k$